# Report Header background colors incorrect in print preview

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have an Access report with group headers (Training Status Good and Bad) that have background colors set by code in the On Paint event.

```
Private Sub GoodBadHeader_Paint()
Dim lngAmber As Long, lngGreen As Long
lngGreen = RGB(76, 204, 79)
lngAmber = RGB(255, 194, 14)

If Me.txtTngStatus.Value = "Good" Then
   Me.GoodBadHeader.BackColor = lngGreen
   Me.GoodBadHeader.AlternateBackColor = lngAmber
Else
   Me.GoodBadHeader.BackColor = lngAmber
   Me.GoodBadHeader.AlternateBackColor = lngGreen
End If
End Sub
```

The colors are good in report view and layout view, but not in print preview or when printed on paper.

Answer (score 0):

Individual formatting for the **Print** views is done in the `On Format` event.

It should work by simply calling your existing sub from there:

```
Private Sub GoodBadHeader_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

    Call GoodBadHeader_Paint

End Sub
```